# Creating a div (with background image) into a link

Tags: css, html, hyperlink, icons

I'm trying to make my little icons on this page (http://www.alinewbury.com/contact.html) into links.
They're each in a div separately, but whenever I try to do:

```
<div class="social-btn pinterest"><a href="http://www.pinterest.com/etc.etc."></a></div>
```

It doesn't seem to work! How can I link these icons to the respective websites?

Comment: I don't see any icons on this page. I'm using Firefox 27.0.1

Comment: try to use span instead of div & that too inside <a> tag.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To make the icon click able you have to fix some issues. First of all your icons are not really linked. you can see the `Hand cursor` because the property defined in the class `.social-btn`

To make a icon clickable you should follow this approach. put the text inside `a` tag a better approach also you have to change the `font-size:0`

```
.social-btn a
{
padding: 22px;
font-size: 0;
}
```

your HTML should be  like this.

```
<div class="social-btn pinterest">
<a href="http://www.pinterest.com/alinewbury/" title="pinterest">pinterest</a>
</div>
```

Comment: If this answer helpful for you. you can vote it or accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Div is supposed to be inside the Anchor tag.

Check Anchor tag [usage](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)